# request.js - cookie creation

Tags: node.js, cookies, request

I'm trying to add a cookie to request.js module [(https://github.com/mikeal/request)](https://github.com/mikeal/request) but I got lost

Does any one have some experience with this ?

The code I've is :

```
 var j = request.jar();
        var cookie = request.cookie('TENANTID');
        j.setCookie(cookie, 'public');


var requestSettings = {
            method: self.method[m],
            url: url.format({
                    pathname : self.getServer() + u,
                    query: {tenant: (process.env.STORM_DB_TENANTS_NAME || 'public')}
                }),
            headers: {'Content-Type': self.headers[h]},
            jar : true
        };
```

The question is how do I combine them ?

Answer (score 2):

in you `requestSettings` you need to assign `jar: j` instead of `jar: true`.

So your `requestSettings` would look like this:

```
var requestSettings = {
    method: self.method[m],
        url: url.format({
            pathname : self.getServer() + u,
            query: {tenant: (process.env.STORM_DB_TENANTS_NAME || 'public')}
        }),
    headers: {'Content-Type': self.headers[h]},
    jar : j    // The request.jar() object you created and added the cookie to.
};
```